# Why does this function return this value?

Tags: python, function, command-line

I have defined a function using Python as follows:

```
def output ():
  print "Hello, world!"

output ()
```

When this script is run in windows command line it will return:

```
Hello, world!
```

What I would like clarified is: why this is? Why is a value output despite there having been no return value defined?

Comment: Because you are calling a method with a `print` inside it. The `print` will *print* to screen.

Comment: The string "Hello, world!" is not returned, but printed to standard output.

Comment: The default return of the method will be `None`. If you do `res = output()` and print out `res`, it will be`None`. But you will still get something printed to screen, because the `print` statement will run when the method is called.

Comment: @idjaw Thank you, I understand now. If you could kindly write that up as an answer I'd be glad to accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default return of the method will be `None`. If you perform the following:

`res = output()`

and print out `res`, it will be `None`. By default, `None` is always returned when not specifying a *return*.

```
>>> def output():
...     print "Hello, world!"
...
>>> res = output()
Hello, world!
>>> res
>>> type(res)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

However, you will still get something printed to screen, because the `print` statement will run when the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

Return values only have a meaning in the context of thinking how the program works. To the end users, they likely know nothing about return values.

A separate concept, output, is what the user typically sees. In this case, the program is using a print statement, which outputs to an output stream called `stdout`. This output stream is typically read by the console the program is running from, and thus outputted to the console.

The actual return value from that function is `None`, but it is never outputted to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Print will print to stdout. That's why.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I don't quite understand what you're saying. Some more exposition would be appreciated. Thanks!